# Rear and front camera open together

Tags: ios, iphone

Can we open rear and front camera together. I checked App in iTunes it is taking pic front camera and rear camera together. I have r&D but I have no proper solutions regarding this features. It is possible we can take pic from front and rear camera together.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't open both cameras at a time. The only option you have it to toggle between the front and back cam.

Even if you do this by using `NSTimer` and toggle at the rate of 0.1 seconds to create an impression that you running both cams at a time, it will effect the camera performance, you will not get clear camera view.

You need to rely on `AVFoundation` to perform this operation if you want to have more control on the camera/video session.

Unfortunately `AVCaptureSession` `startRunning` method runs on `serial queue`, which doesnt allow parallel camera sessions to run.

Comment: Thanks Mr.t for solution but I check one app Dual Cam it is taking pic both side from front and rear camera

Comment: can u provide the link for that app,so that I will have a look into it ? @Lalitkumar

Comment: As I said in my answer, it is not possible to have two camera sessions run at a time. YOu can still take pics from fron and back cams by toggling their sessission!!!!

Comment: Thanks Mr.T for valuable answer.